# Existing Values are not showing up as selected in MUI Autocomplete Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, autocomplete

I have a settings page and there are some steps defined. And, for each step there is an Autocomplete component.
The steps have some users and I need to show the already selected users in the Autocomplete component.
The selected users are appearing in every Autocomplete Component except for the first one. Please check the red marked portion in the screenshot below.

[screenshot of the settings page with Autocomplete Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrc9O.png)

## The React Code

```js
//import statements...
//...

//For Dropdown options of Autocomplete
  const [defaultUsers, setDefaultUsers] = useState([]);

  const getUsers = () => {
    axios
      .get("/user")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setDefaultUsers(res.data.users);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);

//...

//State Variable for steps array
//The users array inside each step need to be shown as selected values in Autocomplete
const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([
    { _id: 1, name: "", type: "", users: [] },
]);

//inputFields state variable is initialized from redux store
 const editFactoryData = useSelector((store) => store.editFactory);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!editFactoryData) {
      navigate("/user/setting");
    } else {
      setFormValues((formValues) => {
        formValues.name = editFactoryData?.name;
        return { ...formValues };
      });
      // setInputFields([...editFactoryData?.steps]);
      let inputFieldError = {};
      let newInputFields = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < editFactoryData?.steps.length; i++) {
        const step = editFactoryData?.steps[i];
        newInputFields.push({ ...step });
        inputFieldError[`${step._id}`] = {
          name: "",
          scannerSuffix: "",
        };
      }
      setInputFields(newInputFields);
      setInputFieldErrors(inputFieldError);
    }
  }, [editFactoryData, navigate]);

//Handle Change function for Autocomplete
const handleUserChange = (value, pos) => {
    console.log(value) ;
    const selectedUsers = value.map((user) => {
      return ({
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name
      })
    })
    setInputFields((inputFields) => {
      inputFields[pos].users = selectedUsers;
      return [...inputFields];
    });
  }

//...

return (
    <>
      <Grid sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <Grid className={style.cards}>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

            //...

            {inputFields ? inputFields.map((inputField, index) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <Grid>
                    <Grid
                      className={[style.plot_shade, style.customer_name]}
                      style={{ paddingRight: 20 }}
                    >
                      <label>Enter Step {index + 1}</label>
                      <br />
                      <Grid key={inputField.id} style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                        <Grid style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                          <input
                            placeholder="Enter step name"
                            type="text"
                            style={{ width: "100%" }}
                            name="name"
                            value={inputFields[index]?.name}
                            onChange={(event) => handleChangeStep(index, event)}
                          />
                        </Grid>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid>
                        <p style={{ color: "red", fontSize: 12 }}>
                          {inputFieldError[inputField.id]?.name}
                        </p>
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>

                  //...
               
                  //AUTOCOMPLETE COMPONENT (Check This)
                  <Grid className={style.plot_shade}>
                    <label>
                      Operators
                    </label>
                    <br/>
                    <Autocomplete
                      multiple
                      options={defaultUsers}
                      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}                  
                      onChange={(_, v) => handleUserChange(v, index)}
                      // renderTags={renderTags}
                      value={inputFields[index].users}
                      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, v) => option.name === v.name}
                      sx={{marginBottom: '20px', marginTop: '4px'}}
                      renderOption={(props, option) => {
                        return (
                          <ListItem
                            {...props}
                            // onClick={() => handleOptionClick(option)}
                            sx={{
                              "&:hover": {
                                backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
                              },
                            }}
                          >
                            {option?.name}
                          </ListItem>
                        );
                      }}
                      renderInput={(params) => (
                        <TextField
                          {...params}
                          placeholder="Select"
                          variant="outlined"
                          focused={false}
                        />
                      )}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                </>
              );
            }) : null}
            <hr />

            <Grid className={style.buttons}>
              <Grid>
                <Button
                  className={style.button1}
                  onClick={handleAddField}
                >
                  Add Step
                </Button>
              </Grid>
              <Grid>
                {isLoading ? (
                  <Button className={style.button1} type="submit" name="submit">
                    <Spinner color="#fff" size="1.5rem" />
                  </Button>
                ) : (
                  <Button className={style.button1} type="submit" name="submit">
                    Save
                  </Button>
                )}

                <Button className={style.button2} onClick={() => goBack()}>Cancel</Button>

              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </form>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}
```

## Redux Data of the Selected Factory

The Following JSON data shows the structure of the factory. The `steps array` shows the structure of each step of a factory. The `users array` inside each `step` object represents the operators of that step. We are showing these operators as selected in Autocomplete Component.

```json
{
  "_id": "1",
  "fId": "f-1",
  "name": "ABC Factory",
  "steps": [
    {
      "category": "1",
      "_id": "1",
      "name": "Step 1",
      "scannerSuffix": "Step 1 type",
      "users": [
        {
          "_id": "1",
          "name": "Operator 1"
        },
        {
          "_id": "2",
          "name": "Operator 2"
        },
        {
          "_id": "3",
          "name": "Operator 3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "2",
      "_id": "2",
      "name": "Step 2",
      "scannerSuffix": "Step 2 type",
      "users": [
        {
          "_id": "1",
          "name": "Operator 1"
        },
        {
          "_id": "2",
          "name": "Operator 2"
        },
        {
          "_id": "3",
          "name": "Operator 3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "3",
      "_id": "2",
      "name": "Step 3",
      "scannerSuffix": "Step 3 type",
      "users": [
        {
          "_id": "1",
          "name": "Operator 1"
        },
        {
          "_id": "2",
          "name": "Operator 2"
        },
        {
          "_id": "3",
          "name": "Operator 3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "1",
      "_id": "4",
      "name": "Step 4",
      "scannerSuffix": "Step 4 type",
      "users": [
        {
          "_id": "1",
          "name": "Operator 1"
        },
        {
          "_id": "2",
          "name": "Operator 2"
        },
        {
          "_id": "3",
          "name": "Operator 3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "5",
      "_id": "5",
      "name": "Step 5",
      "scannerSuffix": "Step 5 type",
      "users": [
        {
          "_id": "1",
          "name": "Operator 1"
        },
        {
          "_id": "2",
          "name": "Operator 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```